# What is the story behind the 'wall girl' in the movie "Deep Dark"?

Tags: plot-explanation, deep-dark

In the movie [*Deep Dark*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2914740/), the main character, a sculptor, talks to a girl who helps him in his artwork. The girl is behind the wall and passes things to the actor.

**What is the story behind the girl in the wall?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is discussed by the Director in a series of interviews and [podcasts](http://slackjawpunks.com/2015/12/07/podcast-138-director-of-deep-dark-michael-medaglia/)

In short, behind the hole is a **monster**. [It's not an (especially) evil monster](http://spanishfear.com/la-mano-fest-interview-to-michael-medaglia-director-of-deep-dark/) so much as powerful and callous:

> *That scene just felt so compelling to me—I eventually created the rest
>   of story around it. But rather than have the Hole be an evil creature,
>   I wanted to portray her as more of a misunderstood, albeit powerful,
>   monster.*

As to *quite why* there's a monster hiding behind his wall, that's never revealed. This is simply the [central conceit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_conceit) of the film and is glossed over with an [airy hand-wave](http://www.darkcomedyprods.com/medaglia.html):

> *The Hole is really just a voice in a wall. With no arms or legs, if
>   she needs get something done she requires other people to do it. So
>   her voice needs to be compelling enough to manipulate people. While
>   writing the script, it helped me to already have a voice in my head
>   for The Hole. For me, that was the strong yet seductive voice of Aeon
>   flux.*